# How to set $_SEVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as attribute within class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to set a property to a class with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Unfortunately, it is fails to work properly.  Below is the way I set it up.

```
<?php

/* Load 404 page if file is accessed directly */
if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"));

class VM_Definitions
{
    private $root;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }
}
$test = new VM_Definitions;
echo $test->root;

?>
```

Comment: That was my typo when entering this question.

Comment: You're trying to access a `private` property outside the function - this [should throw an error](http://codepad.org/VPRLWuQe)

Comment: what is the error you are receiving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you declare the property:

You need to set it like:

```
$this->root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     ^ no more `$`
```

Then if you want to directly access the property, you need to set the visibility to `public`.

Or if you want to preserve it as `private`, setup a getter method:

```
public function getRoot()
{
    return $this->root;
}

$test = new VM_Definitions;
echo $test->getRoot();
```